# Открытие xsd (dataset) Visual Studio

Tags: c#, dataset

При открытии в проекте  xsd (dataset) такая картинка, висит студия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Какая версия студии, для начала?

Comment: 2022 Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Помогло обыкновенное обновление VisualStudio